# implementing delegates in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

This would be the first time I'd use delegates in c# so please bear with me. I've read a lot about them but never thought of how/why to use this construct until now.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public class DoWork()
{

   public MethodWorkA(List<long> TheList) {}

   public void MethodWork1(parameters) {}

   public void MethodWork2(parameters) {}

}
```

I call MethodWorkA from a method outside the class and MethodWorkA calls MethodWork 1 and 2. When I call methodA, I'd like to pass some sort of parameter so that sometimes it just does MethodWork1 and sometimes it does both MethodWork1 and MethodWork2.

So when I call the call it looks like this:

```
DoWork MyClass = new DoWork();
MyClass.MethodA...
```

Where does the delegate syntax fit in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need here any `delegate`, or you confuse here something, or the question is not complete. ?

Comment: @Tigran: because sometimes MethodWorkA needs to call both Work1 and Work2 and sometimes it only needs to call Work1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void MethodWorkA(Action<ParamType1, ParamType2> method) {
    method(...);
}
```

You can call it using method group conversion:

```
MethodWorkA(someInstance.Method1);
```

You can also create a multicast delegate that calls two methods:

```
MethodWorkA(someInstance.Method1 + someInstance.Method2);
```

Comment: ok, and then other times I write MethodWorkA(someInstance.Method1, someInstance.Method2)? Where does the delegate keyword appear?

Comment: The `delegate` keyword is only used to create a new delegate **type**.  You can use the built-in generic `Action<...>` types instead of creating delegate types.

Comment: ok ok cool! and on the first line,  "MethodWorkA(Action<ParamType1, ParamType2> method) {" what is "method"?

Comment: Right now, methodA take a List<long> as parameter; I just leave it as it?

Comment: @SLaks I'm not sure you can combine method references like that (using the plus operator). `Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all methods are inside the same class, and you call `MethodWorkA` function using an *instance* of the class, I honestly, don't see any reason in using `Action<T>` or `delegate`, as is I understood your question.

> When I call methodA, I'd like to pass some sort of parameter so that
>   sometimes it just does MethodWork1 and sometimes it does both
>   MethodWork1 and MethodWork2.

Why do not just pass a simple parameter to `MethodWorkA`, like

```
public class DoWork()
{

   public enum ExecutionSequence {CallMethod1, CallMethod2, CallBoth};
   public MethodWorkA(List<long> TheList, ExecutionSequence exec) 
   {
       if(exec == ExecutionSequence.CallMethod1) 
         MethodWork1(..);
       else if(exec == ExecutionSequence.CallMethod2)
         MethodWork2(..);
       else if(exec == ExecutionSequence.Both)
       {
          MethodWork1(..);
          MethodWork2(..);
       } 
   }

   public void MethodWork1(parameters) {}

   public void MethodWork2(parameters) {}

}
```

Much simplier and understandable for your class consumer.

If this is not what you want, please explain.

**EDIT**

Just to give you an idea what you can do:

Example:

```
public class Executor {

     public void MainMethod(long parameter, IEnumerable<Action> functionsToCall) {
            foreach(Action action in functionsToCall) {
                  action();
            }
     }
}
```

and in the code

```
void Main()
{
    Executor exec = new Executor();
    exec.MainMethod(10, new List<Action>{()=>{Console.WriteLine("Method1");}, 
                                         ()=>{Console.WriteLine("Method2");}
    });
}
```

The output will be

```
Method1
Method2
```

In this way you, for example, can push into the collection only functions you want to execute. Sure, in this case, the decision logic (which functions have to be executed) is determined outside of the call.

Comment: Well my goal is to understand delegates by using them. So I thought my scenario would be a good place to start. I can do without delegates (the code already works without) but I thought of rewriting it with delegates; learning by doing.

Comment: @frenchie: see my edited post for example. Think you're searching for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For what you described, you don't need delegates.

Just do something like this:

```
public class DoWork
{
    public void MethodWorkA(List<long> theList, bool both) 
    {
        if (both)
        {
            MethodWork1(1);
            MethodWork2(1);
        }
        else MethodWork1(1);
    }

    public void MethodWork1(int parameters) { }

    public void MethodWork2(int parameters) { }
}
```

If you're just experimenting with delegates, here goes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Func<string, string> doThis;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doThis = do1;
        Text = doThis("a");
        doThis = do2;
        Text = doThis("a");
    }

    string do1(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        return "1";
    }

    string do2(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        return "2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I already have (very similar, I have a string instead of a bool for the parameter that tells which branch to take). I was looking to implement delegates instead.